# Where is the cairo context object cr declared?

Tags: c, gtk3, cairo

Where, in the following [zetcode](http://zetcode.com/gfx/cairo/basicdrawing/), is the cairo context ***cr*** declared?

```
#include <cairo.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void do_drawing(cairo_t *);

struct {
  int count;
  double coordx[100];
  double coordy[100];
} glob;

static gboolean on_draw_event(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, 
    gpointer user_data)
{
  do_drawing(cr);

  return FALSE;
}

static void do_drawing(cairo_t *cr)
{
  cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
  cairo_set_line_width(cr, 0.5);

  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i <= glob.count - 1; i++ ) {
      for (j = 0; j <= glob.count - 1; j++ ) {
          cairo_move_to(cr, glob.coordx[i], glob.coordy[i]);
          cairo_line_to(cr, glob.coordx[j], glob.coordy[j]);
      }
  }

  glob.count = 0;
  cairo_stroke(cr);    
}

static gboolean clicked(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event,
    gpointer user_data)
{
    if (event->button == 1) {
        glob.coordx[glob.count] = event->x;
        glob.coordy[glob.count++] = event->y;
    }

    if (event->button == 3) {
        gtk_widget_queue_draw(widget);
    }

    return TRUE;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *darea;

  glob.count = 0;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

  darea = gtk_drawing_area_new();
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), darea);

  gtk_widget_add_events(window, GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(darea), "draw", 
      G_CALLBACK(on_draw_event), NULL); 
  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy",
      G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);  

  g_signal_connect(window, "button-press-event", 
      G_CALLBACK(clicked), NULL);

  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 400, 300); 
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Lines");

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Is cairo context ***cr*** automatically declared in the code and associated with the ***darea*** (unfortunate name for drawing area) when we call the function

```
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(darea), "draw", 
      G_CALLBACK(on_draw_event), NULL);
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The widget will emit the signal and pass it's internal cairo context. When you connect a callback to handle the signal, cairo context is sent by the widget, you receive it and work on it.

**Draw** signal belongs to Gtk Widget class:

```
gboolean user_function (GtkWidget *widget, CairoContext *cr, gpointer user_data)
```

From the [draw documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-draw):

> This signal is emitted when a widget is supposed to render itself. The
>   widget 's top left corner must be painted at the origin of the passed
>   in context and be sized to the values returned by
>   gtk_widget_get_allocated_width() and
>   gtk_widget_get_allocated_height().
>
> Signal handlers connected to this signal can modify the cairo context
>   passed as cr in any way they like and don't need to restore it. The
>   signal emission takes care of calling cairo_save() before and
>   cairo_restore() after invoking the handler.
>
> The signal handler will get a cr with a clip region already set to the
>   widget's dirty region, i.e. to the area that needs repainting.
>   Complicated widgets that want to avoid redrawing themselves completely
>   can get the full extents of the clip region with
>   gdk_cairo_get_clip_rectangle(), or they can get a finer-grained
>   representation of the dirty region with
>   cairo_copy_clip_rectangle_list().

Comment: thanks! Is any widget allowed a single drawing context then?

Comment: Widgets can only draw on the given Cairo context. You can create any other Cairo surface at any point, but if you want it displayed on the screen, you need to use it with the Cairo context that GTK+ gives you.

Comment: indeed, as ebassi said. Widgets expose their internal cairo context. you can create others but they won't show on the widget, to do so you must use the widget internal cairo context that gets exposed.

Answer (score -1):

I also hated the CairoContext *cr is
not defined but is simply cairo_t *cr