# Access to Cairo context 'cr' in GTK window

Tags: c, gtk3, cairo

In this simple example, inside the function  `do_draw` cairo knows on which surface to draw since it is using the argument `cairo_t * cr` . I don't understand where `cr` comes from, I suppose it was automatically created by GTK with the creation of the widget `drawarea`.
I want to draw (more complicated) stuff on that same `cr` from outside the `do_draw` function, but I don't know how to access `cr` from another function?

```
#include <cairo.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

// gcc move.c -o move $(pkg-config --cflags --libs cairo --libs gtk+-3.0)

gboolean timer = TRUE;
int i = 1;


static gboolean do_draw(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer user_data)
{
    cairo_select_font_face(cr, "Courier", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_BOLD);
    cairo_set_font_size(cr, 60);
    cairo_move_to(cr, i, 300);
    cairo_show_text(cr, "moving");
    return FALSE;
}

static gboolean time_handler(GtkWidget *widget)
{
    if (i > 15) return FALSE;
    printf("drawing frame %d\n", i);
    gtk_widget_queue_draw(widget);
    i++;
    return TRUE;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // gtk inits
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    GtkWidget *window  = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    GtkWidget *drawarea = gtk_drawing_area_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), drawarea);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 800, 600);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(drawarea), "draw", G_CALLBACK(do_draw), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    // timer
    g_timeout_add(200, (GSourceFunc) time_handler, (gpointer) window);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as i understand, it looks as if 'cr' was automatically created by GTK with the creation of the widget drawarea.

No, it's a wrapper around the graphics context provided by the windowing system draw event. Whether or not that is re-created every draw is windowing system-dependent, but you cannot get that handle without *being* in a draw event.

Under Windows, for example, `WM_PAINT` gets the drawing context with `BeginPaint` in its handler. But if you want to create your own context elsewhere you use `GetDC` to get one instead.

Gtk however only supports the paint event to draw on widgets (ie the first half of the above). So you cannot get a drawing context outside a paint event, you need to trigger the paint event and let it draw itself.

Comment: so does that mean that my only solution would be to call my function as this :`do_draw_more(cairo_t * cr)` from inside `do_draw`?

Comment: Yeah, you can only draw from inside your draw handler.

Comment: found similar question here : [so 43633012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43633012/where-is-the-cairo-context-object-cr-declared?rq=1).